# Event listener not working on anchor

Tags: javascript, anchor

This may be a very dumb question, but I'm desperate right now. I'm trying to execute a javascript function by clicking on an anchor like this:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        alert('It was clicked');
    }
    Anchor.addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
</script>
</head>
…
<a href="#" id="Anchor">Click me</a>
```

But it's not working.

However, this works fine:

```
<a href="javascript:myFunction()" id="Anchor">Click me</a>
```

And even this does:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()" id="Anchor">Click me</a>
```

What is the correct way to go? What am I doing wrong? A [jsfiddle for example here](http://jsfiddle.net/arielnmz/9L4xbsjx/).

Extra info:

I have set up other events using the same method, but somehow the anchor is the only one that doesn't work. Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function aFunction() {
        AnElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', aFunction, false);
</script>
```

And the element is hidden perfectly fine when the window has finished loading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you were placing your script on `HEAD` section. `Anchor` doesn't exist by the time the script is executed and because of this you were getting `Anchor is not defined`.

Try this modified version that place the script after the html definition.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/claudioredi/z7h495rd/)

```
<a href="#" id="Anchor">Click me</a>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        alert('It was clicked');
    }
    Anchor.addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Please put the code in the answer, not just a link.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of that. I thought symbols were evaluated after the document was loaded.

Comment: @arielnmz Scripts are executed as soon as they're encountered while the document is being loaded. This allows things like `document.write()` to generate HTML at the point in the document where the script appears.

Answer (score 6):

you shoul add your bind after pageload event, and use getElementById.

```
function myFunction() {
    alert('It was clicked');
}
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('Anchor').addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

Comment: I can see now why is my event listener not working thanks to Claudio, and your solution works perfectly fine from the `head`. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Just because you give the tag an id attribute like `id="Anchor"` doesn't mean you can call it directly from javascript like you do: `Anchor.addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);`

You actually have to find the element before binding an event.

```
document.getElementById('Anchor').addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
```

Comment: Actually, yes you can. IDs are turned into global variables.

Comment: @Barmar, in some places. This is not across the board and is *certainly* not a good idea.